# How to apply nice LDplot?

Tags: r, plot, dataframe, heatmap, gplots

I have data as below. I have found linkage disequilibrium (LD) between my data (chromosomes positions) and Now I like draw a plot like heatmap or other plots that show relation between columns S1 and S2.

Input:

```
           S1        S2          R^2
1 10 73576307   11 308290 9.648065e-05
2 10 73576307   11 309127 5.023692e-04
3   11 308290   11 309127 3.927666e-01
4 10 73576307 1 158813819 1.227192e-04
5   11 308290 1 158813819 1.404745e-03
```

Thanks for your hep in advance.